# Finding differences and similarities between tree graphs

Tags: graphs, trees

Are there any known techniques for "diffing" trees, such as [phylogenetic trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylogenetic_tree)?

Comment: One way is to look at all triples of elements and check relations (who is a child of who) between their least common ancestors (there are 3 of them, two must be the same, one must be their child (or be the same as them)). You may deduct scores when the relation is different. I've no idea how good this measure is. For better understanding, you can check e.g. http://proceedings.mlr.press/v80/chatziafratis18a/chatziafratis18a.pdf or https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.02715.pdf